# Convert image in Mat object to a Float Array in Android

Tags: android, opencv

I am reading an image in Android and I want to access the pixel values of the image.

I am reading the images like this

```
Mat img1 = new Mat();
img1 = Highgui.imread(filePath1);
```

Is there an efficient way to convert the Mat object to a float array?

Currently, I am doing it like this & this is very slow.

```
private float[][] convertToFloatArray(String filePath1){

    img1 = Highgui.imread(filePath1);
    String output = img1.dump();
    float[][] flt = new float[img1.rows()][img1.cols()];

    // slowest step but necessary to remove [, ;, etc.
    String array1[] = output.split("[^0-9]+"); 

    int k = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i<img1.rows();i++) {
        for(int j = 0;j<img1.cols();j++) {
            flt[i][j] = (Float.valueOf(array1[k])).floatValue();
            k += 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Cannot believe that you should dump to a string first. Then split the string to get the pixel values. There must be an easier way.

Comment: And why do you want floats? Why not integers?

Comment: @greenapps: Even integers would do. Do you know a way to convert to ints?

Comment: I know nothing. I only wondered why you would dump all to a string first and then split the string in values. I said that i supposed that there would be other -better- methods. You did not react on that.

Comment: If I knew a better method, I wouldn't ask here ^-^

Comment: Take a look at http://answers.opencv.org/question/4761/mat-to-byte-array/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to figure out a solution

```
        img1 = new Mat();
        img1 = Highgui.imread(filePath1, 0);
        int buff[] = new int[(int)img1.total() * img1.channels()];
        img1.get(0, 0, buff);
        return buff;
```

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned int array would be fine. You can skip the string float and string lines you are using above and just use this:

```
  int k = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i<img1.rows();i++) {
        for(int j = 0;j<img1.cols();j++) {
            int_arr[i][j] = static_cast<unsigned>(img1.data[k]);
            k += 1;
        }
    }
```

Also keep track of how many channels you have.

Comment: Static_cast is not a thing in Java. This doesn't work